# Unity: Change volume of an AudioSource array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm new to coding and I have a question. I want to mute every AudioSource inside my array but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the error message I get:

> error CS1061: 'AudioSource[]' does not contain a definition for
> 'volume' and no accessible extension method 'volume' accepting a first
> argument of type 'AudioSource[]' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

I manually put the AudioSources into the inspector. I don't necessarily wanna use `GetComponent`. In the inspector it's clearly registered as an AudioSource and NOT as a `GameObject`, that's why I'm confused why it's telling me that volume is not an accessible extension.

Thanks in advance!

This is my script:

```cs
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource[] sfxSources;

    public void ToggleSFX()
    {
        foreach (var AudioSource in sfxSources)
        {
            sfxSources.volume = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to create a private AudioSource, let's say "test", and put it manually into the inspector it would work setting the audio with `test.volume = 0f;`

So why is not working for an array?

Answer (score 0):

`sfxSources` is your array (`AudioSource[]`), your array element is `AudioSource` in this case. Which by the way is a terrible name, both from a convention point of view and just in general.

So you want to write something like this instead:

```
    foreach (var audioSource in sfxSources)
        audioSource.volume = 0f;
```